# Converting multiple csv (specific date range) to shp using ArcPy

Tags: arcpy, arcmap, arcgis-10.0, csv, datetime

[image]

I have multiples CSV files. Every CSV file contains 365 days of different weather parameters for different location. I want to take specific month from every csv row and export it to point shp file using ArcPy.

Can you help me to do it using ArcPy?

In csv date format is (MM DD YY)

Below is my Python code.This code is giving me an error while I run it date specific.

```
import arcpy,os
... shpworkspace = r"D:\SWAT-WEATHER-DATA2"
... arcpy.env.workspace = shpworkspace
... arcpy.env.overwriteOutput = True
... 
... csvlist = arcpy.ListFiles("*.csv")
... 
... for csvfile in csvlist:
    print csvfile
    outlayer = "CSVEventLayer"
    spatialreference = "GEOGCS['GCS_WGS_1984',DATUM['D_WGS_1984',SPHEROID['WGS_1984',6378137.0,298.257223563]],PRIMEM['Greenwich',0.0],UNIT['Degree',0.0174532925199433]];-400 -400 1000000000;-100000 10000;-100000 10000;8.98315284119522E-09;0.001;0.001;IsHighPrecision"
    arcpy.MakeXYEventLayer_management(csvfile,"Longitude","Latitude","Date 1/1/2013-1/31/2013",outlayer,spatialreference,"#")

    shpfile = os.path.splitext(csvfile)[0].replace('-','_')        
    arcpy.CopyFeatures_management(outlayer,shpfile)

    del outlayer
```

I have edited my code based on suggestions from different expert. Still I am getting an error.

```
import arcpy,os
... shpworkspace = r"D:\SWAT-WEATHER-DATA4"
... arcpy.env.workspace = shpworkspace
... arcpy.env.overwriteOutput = True
... 
... csvlist = arcpy.ListFiles("*.csv")
... 
... for csvfile in csvlist:
    print csvfile
    outlayer = "CSVEventLayer"
    spatialreference = "GEOGCS['GCS_WGS_1984',DATUM['D_WGS_1984',SPHEROID['WGS_1984',6378137.0,298.257223563]],PRIMEM['Greenwich',0.0],UNIT['Degree',0.0174532925199433]];-400 -400 1000000000;-100000 10000;-100000 10000;8.98315284119522E-09;0.001;0.001;IsHighPrecision"
    arcpy.MakeXYEventLayer_management(csvfile,"Longitude","Latitude",outlayer,spatialreference,"#")
    arcpy.SelectLayerByAttribute_management(outlayer, "NEW_SELECTION", "Date" >= date "01/01/2013 00:00:00" AND "Date" < date "01/31/2013 00:00:00")  
    shpfile = os.path.splitext(csvfile)[0].replace('-','_')    
    arcpy.CopyFeatures_management(outlayer,shpfile)

    del outlayer
```

Answer (score 1):

Remove "Date 1/1/2013-1/31/2013" from the arguments of MakeXYEventLayer.
Add something like:

```
   arcpy.SelectLayerByAttribute_management(outlayer, "NEW_SELECTION", ' "Date" = <whatever> ')  
# This selects the points with the right date.

    arcpy.CopyFeatures_management(outlayer, shpfile) 
# This copies the selected ones into an .shp.
```

This is just a structure to guide you.  The field name may not actually be "Date."  You will need to inspect the output of MakeXYEventLayer and/or put header rows into the csv's to define the field names.